# How to revert multiple commit from branch created out of master?

Tags: git

How can I revert multiple commits from a branch created out of master ?

I created a release-`1.1` from master. Master includes a jira with following commits. A jira has around 50 commits. Example as below , it has also merge commits in between marked (M)

**commits**

```
a364478
b236478
cweyriw(M)
ywkherr
u498hsd
i93wrff(M)
eryiwrr
werkiwr 
...
...
....
```

Comment: Don't look at that branch and it will go away. Or just delete it. Commits are immutable, so you can just ignore them.

Comment: Master includes that JIRA with commits

Comment: What is "a jira"?

Comment: @isherwood I guess i's a task on a feature branch that contains some 50 revisions for itself.

Comment: JIRA is Atlassian's project management board, used with BitBucket.

Comment: Not sure about reverting multiple commits but if it's ok to just remove those commits: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html. Follow this guide and use the flag "d" for the commits you want to delete

Answer (score 1):

Here is the technique -

**Method 1 :** Cherry-pick `Your Commits` alone.
I guess, you do not have to think about others commit. So just pick your commits and go ahead. 
Commands to follow:
Assuming commit x & y are committed by you.
Assuming you are in the branch (jira branch)
a. `git fetch origin`
b. `git log --oneline -30` #Note down your commit ID somewhere (x&y)
c. `git reset --hard origin/master` #BE CAREFUL there should not be any non committed files. Which will destroy this command, if any!
d. `git cherry-pick commit-x` 
e. `git cherry-pick commit-y`
g. `Do the required code changes` for reverting 
h. `git commit..` new changes
f. `git log --oneline -20` #to confirm

**Method 2** : Use revert command.
Assuming commit-a and commit-b you want to revert
a. `git revert commit-a` 
b. `git revert commit-b` 
Please note, this will create new two commits above all.